# Submit form and prepopulate custom fields in DocuSign Envelope

Tags: php, forms, docusignapi

For some reason I can't get my code to show the custom fields I am wanting to add in the left pane(e.g. First Name, Last Name, etc.). On submit my form should go to the envelope and prepopulate my custom fields. I've searched the DocuSign docs and also different threads on here. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    // Input your info:
    $email = "foor@bar.com";                                 // your account email
    $password = "password";                              // your account password
    $integratorKey = "wouldnt-you-like-to-know"; // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)
    $templateId = "66b7706e-936b-4438-bd5e-bd68ce47dffb";    // provide a valid templateId of a template in your account
    $templateRoleName = "Test";                              // use same role name that exists on the template in the console

    $recipientName = 'blah bleh';                        // provide a recipient (signer) name
    $recipientEmail = 'yee@haw.com';
                                                             // the recipient name and email.  Whatever you set the clientUserId to you must use the same
                                                             // value when requesting the signing URL
                                                             // construct the authentication header:
    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $animal = $_POST['animal'];

    $header = 
    "<DocuSignCredentials>
        <Username>" . 
            $email . 
        "</Username>
        <Password>" . 
            $password . 
        "</Password>
        <IntegratorKey>" . 
            $integratorKey . 
        "</IntegratorKey>
    </DocuSignCredentials>";

    // STEP 1 - Login (retrieves baseUrl and accountId)
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($curl);

    //--- display results
    echo "accountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n" . "<br>";

    // STEP 2 - Create an envelope with an Embedded recipient (uses the clientUserId property)
    $data = array(
        "accountId" => $accountId, 
        "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Embedded Signing Example",
        "emailBlurb" => "This is a test.",
        "compositeTemplates" => array(
            "serverTemplates" => array(
                "sequence" => "1",
                "templateId" => $templateId
            ),
            "inlineTemplates" => array(
                "sequence" => "2",
                "recipients" => array(
                    "signers" => array(
                        "roleName" => "Signer1",
                        "recipientId" => "1",
                        "name" => "John Doe",
                        "email" => "johndoe@test.com",
                        "clientUserId" => "1234",
                        "tabs" => array(
                            "textTabs" => array(
                                "tabLabel" => "address",
                                "value" => "123 Main Street"
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        "status" => "sent"
    );    

    $data_string = json_encode($data);  
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> <br>";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];
    curl_close($curl);

    //--- display results   
    echo "<br>Envelope created! Envelope ID: " . $envelopeId . "\n"; 

    // STEP 3 - Get the Embedded Signing View 
    $data = array(
        "returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
        "authenticationMethod" => "Email", 
        "clientUserId" => "1234",
        "userName" => "John Doe",
        "email" => "johnDoe@test.com"
    );   

    $data_string = json_encode($data);    
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 201 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $url = $response["url"];

    //--- display results
    echo "\n\nNavigate to this URL to start the embedded signing view of the envelope\n" . "<br>Embedded URL is: \n\n" . "<a href='$url'>HERE!</a>"; 
}
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<label for="color">color:</label>
<input type="text" name="color">
<br>
<label for="number">number:</label>
<input type="text" name="number">
<br>
<label for="animal">animal:</label>
<input type="text" name="animal">
<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an Envelope using a Template and pre-populate field(s) within that Envelope's documents requires that you use the *Composite Templates* structure in the API request. (See the "Composite Templates" section on [this page](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) for info about Composite Templates.)

I'm not familiar with the DocuSign PHP SDK, but will explain the request syntax in JSON, and I imagine you can figure out the corresponding PHP syntax to generate the requests as shown.

The following example request (JSON) creates an Envelope that uses the specified Template with a single recipient (role name = *Signer1*), and pre-populates the **address** field with value "123 Main Street" for that recipient (embedded signer). (Although this example pre-fills just a single field for *Signer1* -- you could obviously pre-fill additional fields by simply including them in the tabs object of the request along with **address**.)

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi//v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes

{
    "emailSubject": "Test Pre-fill Tabs",
    "emailBlurb": "This is a test.",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "CD0E6D53-3447-4A9E-BBAF-0EB2C78E8310"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates":[{
            "sequence": "2",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [
                    {
                        "roleName": "Signer1",
                        "recipientId": "1",
                        "name": "John Doe",
                        "email": "johndoe@test.com",
                        "clientUserId": "1234",
                        "tabs": {
                            "textTabs": [
                                {
                                    "tabLabel": "address",
                                    "value": "123 Main Street"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }]
    }],
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Once you've created the Envelope (using the above request), you'll execute a "POST Recipient View" request to get the signing URL for *Signer1*:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi//v2/accounts/{{accountId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId/views/recipient

{
    "clientUserId": "1234",
    "userName": "John Doe",
    "email": "johndoe@test.com",
    "returnUrl": "https://www.google.com",
    "authenticationMethod": "Email"
}
```

(Notice that you don't specify tabs in this request.)

---

UPDATE #1

---

Starting with the code you added to your original post, I've been able to modify it such that it's now successfully creating an Envelope (using a Template), with a single *embedded* recipient (**Signer1**) and pre-populating the **address** text field for that signer.  Here is the code -- please note that you'll need to specify values for all variables at the top of this code example.

```
<?php

// Set values for variables
//-----------
$email = "YOUR_DOCUSIGN_LOGIN_EMAIL";                                 // your account email
$password = "YOUR_DOCUSIGN_LOGIN_PASSWORD";                              // your account password
$integratorKey = "YOUR_DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATOR_KEY"; // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)

$templateId = "TEMPLATE_ID";    // provide a valid templateId of a template in your account
$templateRoleName = "TEMPLATE_RECIPIENT_ROLE_NAME";                              // use same role name that exists on the template in the console

$recipientName = "SIGNER_NAME";                        // provide a recipient (signer) name
$recipientEmail = "SIGNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS";            // provide a recipient (signer) email address
$recipientId = "1";                                 // set recipient id (can be any integer value)
$clientUserId = "1234";                             // set clientUserId (can be any integer value) -- this is what makes the recipient an "embedded recipient (signer)"

$header = 
"<DocuSignCredentials>
    <Username>" . 
        $email . 
    "</Username>
    <Password>" . 
        $password . 
    "</Password>
    <IntegratorKey>" . 
        $integratorKey . 
    "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";



// STEP 1 - Login (retrieves baseUrl and accountId)
//-----------
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "\n";
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "accountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n\n";



// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with an Embedded recipient (uses the clientUserId property)
//-----------
// tabs
$textTabs = array();
$textTabs[] = array('tabLabel' => "address", 'value' => "123 Main Street");             
$tabs = array('textTabs' => $textTabs);
#echo ("tabs:\n" . json_encode($tabs) . "\n\n");

// recipients 
$signers = array();
$signers[] = array('roleName' => $templateRoleName, 'recipientId' => $recipientId, 'name' => $recipientName, 'email' => $recipientEmail, 'clientUserId' => $clientUserId, 'tabs' => $tabs);
$recipients = array('signers' => $signers);
#echo ("recipients:\n" . json_encode($recipients) . "\n\n");

// serverTemplates
$serverTemplates = array();
$serverTemplates[] = array('sequence' => "1", 'templateId' => $templateId);
#echo ("serverTemplates:\n " . json_encode($serverTemplates) . "\n\n");

// inlineTemplates
$inlineTemplates = array();
$inlineTemplates[] = array('sequence' => "2", 'recipients' => $recipients);
#echo ("inlineTemplates:\n" . json_encode($inlineTemplates) . "\n\n");

// compositeTemplates
$compositeTemplates = array();
$compositeTemplates[] = array('serverTemplates' => $serverTemplates ,'inlineTemplates' => $inlineTemplates);
#echo ("compositeTemplates:\n" . json_encode($compositeTemplates) . "\n\n");

// request body 
$data = array('emailSubject' => "DocuSign Test - Embedded Signing", 'emailBlurb' => "Please sign. Thanks!", 'status' => 'sent', 'compositeTemplates' => $compositeTemplates);
$data_string = json_encode($data);  

$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> \n";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results   
echo "\nEnvelope created! Envelope ID: " . $envelopeId . "\n"; 



// STEP 3 - Get the Embedded Signing View 
//-----------
$data = array(
    "returnUrl" => "http://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
    "authenticationMethod" => "Email", 
    "clientUserId" => $clientUserId,
    "userName" => $recipientName,
    "email" => $recipientEmail
);   

$data_string = json_encode($data);    
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/$envelopeId/views/recipient" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$url = $response["url"];

//--- display results
echo "\n\nNavigate to this URL to start the embedded signing view of the envelope:\n\n" . $url . "\n\n"; 

?>
```

*Disclaimer: although this code is functional and achieves the objective, this is my first foray into working with PHP, so there's likely a better (more efficient) way to write this code. I welcome feedback if any PHP experts are so inclined.*

Comment: I get this error:

    { "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY", "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API_REST.Models.v2.compositeTemplate]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: This means DocuSign is expecting an array in a place where you're specifying an object. Examine the full trace of your request (using Fiddler or a similar tool) and compare it to the example I've provided -- make sure your request is specifying an array for compositeTemplates (and also serverTemplates, InlineTemplates, etc.).

Comment: Cannot figure this out. I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now. I initially thought that putting fields from a form into a DocuSign document would be elementary but this is extremely time-consuming and their docs do not provide an answer to what i'm looking for.

Comment: If you can update your post/question with a full trace of your current (non-working) JSON request and the JSON response you're getting back, I'd be happy to provide input on what needs changed. To capture the full trace (JSON request/response), you can use a tool like Fiddler...start Fiddler then execute your code...Fiddler will show you the JSON request/response.

Comment: I've installed Fiddler but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking at, I have never used it before. I cannot update my original question with my script. I would have to add it as a new comment and I don't believe it would fit.

Comment: The problem is that there are hardly any docs on implementing the DocuSign REST API using PHP. I even tried using the SOAP SDK DocuSign PHP Client but it gave me an error saying that the SOAP base class was missing. So I scrapped the idea of using the PHP Client and went back to the REST API. And once again I'm stuck, thank you for your help. Just a bit frustrated right now because this is for work!

Comment: I've updated the original question with my entire script. Sorry if it gives you headache, just wanted to provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I'll try to find time later today to play around with it a bit and hopefully give you some working code.

Comment: Just now getting back to this.  It's taken me a bit of time, but I've installed & configured PHP on my machine and have run your code to see what JSON request/response it produces.  As I expected (and stated above), your JSON request is specifying objects (i.e., {...} ) in places where arrays of objects are expected (i.e., [{...}, {...}]).  I'm out of time for the day but will spend a few minutes tomorrow to try to fix your PHP code. No promises, as I haven't ever used PHP before, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Okay, I've just added "Update #1" to my answer -- which includes functional PHP sample code that achieves your objective. Once you've verified this working, please mark this as an "Accepted" answer so that others may benefit from it in the future. Thanks!